# Pagination with meteor

Tags: meteor, pagination

am trying to list 9 items each time and i found `alethes:pages` that can help accomplish it.
i didn't understand how exactly it should be implemented.
My collection is created with

```
Products = new Mongo.Collection("products");
```

so i created the Pages inside /lib folder

```
Pages = new Meteor.Pagination(Products, {
    perPage: 9,
    sort: {
        createdAt: -1
    }
});
```

Am confused on how to use the `Pages` to list the items? below is my template to list the items. Am calling the template inside another template to list the items.

This is the template

```
<template name="list_products">
    {{#each applications}}
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="{{previewImage}}" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

How do i apply `Pages` to `list_products` template?

sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

This how you have to define your template and item template for pages.

```
Pages = new Meteor.Pagination(Products, {
    perPage: 9,
    sort: {
        createdAt: -1
    }
    templateName: "list_products",
    itemTemplate: "list_products_item",
});
```

Then your list_products have the following templates {{> pages}} and  {{> pagesNav}} like this :

```
<template name="list_products">
    {{> pages}}
    {{> pagesNav}}
</template>
```

And here how you have to create your each item template which will show your item and you don't have to use any #each for that. Basically it will render each time based of your item per page value:

```
<template name="list_products_item">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="{{previewImage}}" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```